# Discord.js v12 How to get total number on reactions from fetched embed

Tags: discord.js

So i've been trying to count the reactions statistic after it was accepted or rejected, i'd try to find a solution but i can't here's my code

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'accept-suggestion',
  cooldown: 3,
  description: 'Accept a sugegstion',
  permissions: 'MANAGE_ROLES',
  usage: '[suggestion id] [reason]',
  async run(client, message, args, cmd, Discord){
    message.delete()
    const messageID = args[0];
    const acceptMsg = args.slice(1).join(" ");

    if(!messageID) return message.reply('Please specify a suggestion Id!').then(msg => {
      msg.delete({ timeout: 3000 })
    })
    if(!acceptMsg) return message.reply('Please specify a reason!').then(msg => {
      msg.delete({ timeout: 3000})
    })

    try {
      const suggestionChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(
        'SuggestionChannel_ID'
      );

      const moderator = message.author.tag

      const suggestedEmbed = await suggestionChannel.messages.fetch(messageID);
      console.log(suggestedEmbed)
      const data = suggestedEmbed.embeds[0];
      const dataStats = suggestedEmbed[0];

      let upVote = dataStats.reactions.cache.get('✅').count;
      let downVote = dataStats.reactions.cache.get('❌').count;


      const acceptEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Suggestion (Accepted)")
        .setColor('#1dc44a')
        .setAuthor(data.author.name, data.author.iconURL)
        .setDescription(data.description)
        .addFields(
          {name: `Accepted by ${moderator}`, value: ` > ${acceptMsg}`},
          {name: 'Statistic', value: `${upVote}\n${downVote}`}
        )
        .setFooter(`${data.author.name}'s suggestion`, data.author.iconURL)

      suggestedEmbed.edit(acceptEmbed).then(msg => msg.reactions.removeAll())

      const user = await client.users.cache.find(
        (u) => u.tag === data.author.name
      );
      user.send("Your suggestion has been accepted!")
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
}
```

you maybe wondering why i put .reactions after dataStats, i put it because i thought it would work by seeing the output off the suggestedEmbed(the output: https://pastebin.com/yEhDecur) i hope someone could fix this :)

Comment: V12 Has been depreceated

Comment: "So i've been trying to count the reactions statistic after it was accepted or rejected, i'd try to find a solution but i can't here's my code" Very vague and not helpful. More detail like which line exactly has the code you tried and didn't work, which embed you are tyring to get the number of reactions from....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the `fetch()` method with a id parameter only returns a single Message so accessing it like a array/collection won't work

```js
      const dataStats = suggestedEmbed[0];
```

this needs to change to

```js
      const dataStats = suggestedEmbed;
```

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch

[image]